# How to call an activity from a class extending ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, popup

My main class is principal extends activity

with this code call MiMapa class:

```
switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.presentLocation_button:
            Log.i("Button","Button 3 pushed");
            Intent m = new Intent(this, MiMapa.class);
            startActivity(m);
        break;
```

work perfect.

MiMapa class is :

```
public class MiMapa extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
```

I have this method:

```
public void setOverlay1(){  
        int foodLength = foodItem.length;
        // Create itemizedOverlay2 if it doesn't exist and display all three items
        if(! foodIsDisplayed){
        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();    
        drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.golf); 
        itemizedOverlay1 = new Ofertas(drawable1); 
        // Display all three items at once
        for(int i=0; i<foodLength; i++){
            itemizedOverlay1.addOverlay(foodItem[i]);
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay1);
        foodIsDisplayed = !foodIsDisplayed;
        // Remove each item successively with button clicks
        } else {            
            itemizedOverlay1.removeItem(itemizedOverlay1.size()-1);
            if((itemizedOverlay1.size() < 1))  foodIsDisplayed = false;
        }    
        // Added symbols will be displayed when map is redrawn so force redraw now
        mapView.postInvalidate(); 
    }
```

now the problem.

into Ofertas class ( public class Ofertas extends ItemizedOverlay {)

in the tap method My code is:

```
protected boolean onTap(int i){
        GeoPoint  gpoint = myOverlays.get(i).getPoint();

        double lat = gpoint.getLatitudeE6()/1e6;
        double lon = gpoint.getLongitudeE6()/1e6;

        String toast = "Title: "+myOverlays.get(i).getTitle();
        toast += "\nText: "+myOverlays.get(i).getSnippet();
        toast +=    "\nSymbol coordinates: Lat = "+lat+" Lon = "+lon+" (microdegrees)";
        Toast.makeText(principal.context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(principal.context,Popup.class);
        principal.context.startActivity(intent);
        intent.putExtra("message", "My popup number " + mCount);
        mCount++;
        //startActivity(intent);
        return(true);
    }
```

but don't work.
I had tried 
intent.setClass(MiMapa.context,Popup.class);
or
intent.setClass(principal.this,Popup.class);
or
intent.setClass(MiMapa.this,Popup.class);

Nothing work.

please, help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your `Activity` into your `ItemizedOverlay` (e.g., via the constructor) and use that for your `startActivity()` call.